# Number system based word problem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Problem statement

> If x and y are two digits of the number 653xy such that this number is divisible by 80, then what is x+y.

80 = 2^4 * 5;

what I have so far-- since 5 divides 653xy, so y=0 or y=5.

I can't deduce any more information.

Could somebody help me with this?

Comment: And since $10$ divides $653xy$, so?

Comment: Since $1000$ is divisible by $80$, you are actually looking at $3xy$. You can say more about $y$, and that will tell you exactly what $x$ is.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin How is 1000 divisible by 80? it gives remainder of 40?

Comment: Directly perform long division $65300/80$, and think what the remainder mean.

Comment: sorry. 1000 is divisible by $8$, so $10000$ is divisible by $80$. You are really just trying to figure out what $x$ makes $53x$ divisible by $8$.